# Separate and change case of string columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, case, separator

I have created a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

ds1 = {'Name':["SANAVBARI NIKITENKO","ALEXANDER SASHA ROMANOV","Axmadova Aminat Ramzanovna"]}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ds1)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df1)
                         Name
0         SANAVBARI NIKITENKO
1     ALEXANDER SASHA ROMANOV
2  Axmadova Aminat Ramzanovna
```

I need to create a new column (called `matchKey`) in which the first letter of each word inside the column `Name` is in upper case and the rest of the word is in lower case.
From the example above, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it in python by any chance, please?

Comment: `df['matchKey'] = df['Name'].str.title()`